# How can I implement SWReveal for iOS navigation with back buttons

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

I try to use **SWReveal** to manage menu and views in an iOS app.
No problem for implement it.

The **'sw_front'** view controller is the home for the app. There's 4 buttons to access to 4 different screens.
The **'sw_rear'** view controller is the menu to access screens directly.

For others screens, I want a **'back button'** to return to the home of the app **'sw_front'**. When I acces screens from 'sw_front', everything works fine, I've got a 'back button'. But when I access screen from 'sw_rear', I can't have 'back button'. I also want when user tap on 'back button', he return automatically on 'sw_front' (app home) and not on 'sw_rear'.

Here is a screenshot
[image: SWReveal navigation between views]

How can I achieve this ? I didn't find informations or examples.

So please, help me !

Thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the back button, technically speaking. When you click a button in sw_rear, it is not pushing a view controller on top of the home view.

May be try adding a back button elsewhere, and try

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I completely change the logic and it's work ! When I click on a menu item, I push a view in HomeViewController navigation.

Comment: @kopacabana Can you please create an answer with your solution? I mean, how to organize the viewControllers.

Comment: Hi @JCarlos I try to give you more informations asap but I'm completely submerged. Please send me new message if you haven't informations about me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I add a new ViewController between SWRevealViewController and NavigationViewController. This viewController is connect to SWRevealViewController as 'sw_rear'. I remove segue from my existing NavigationController.

In this new ViewController, I create my NavigationController with :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav") as! UINavigationController
navVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
self.view.addSubview(navVC.view)
self.addChildViewController(navVC)
```

Now I can add screens to my NavigationViewController

```
navVC.push(otherViewController)
```

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your new Storyboard?